# DevExpress LookupEdit, Select by item

Tags: winforms, devexpress

How to set selected element of DevExpress LookupEdit by item? I.e., given one object of the LookupEdit's datasource, set the selection of the LookupEdit based on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I found the answer in the [DevExpress forums](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q368250). Just let the `ValueMember` property unassigned, and set the `EditValue` property of the control to the item to be selected. Taking @DmitryG example:

```
var dataSource = new List<Person>();
p1 = new Person(){ ID=0, Name="John", Age=27 };
dataSource.Add(p1);
//...
dataSource.Add(new Person(){ ID=101, Name="Mary", Age=23 });
lookupEdit1.Properties.DataSource = dataSource;
lookupEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "Name";
//...
lookupEdit1.EditValue = p1;
```

In this situation, it will be bound to the reference to an item.

Answer (score 4):

You should set the [LookupEdit.EditValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseEdit_EditValuetopic) property with value from your data source according to [LookupEdit.ValueMember](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEditBase_ValueMembertopic) property.

Here is the sample that demonstrated this approach:

```
var dataSource = new List<Person> { 
    new Person(){ ID=0, Name="John", Age=27 },
    //...
    new Person(){ ID=101, Name="Mary", Age=23 },
};
lookupEdit1.Properties.DataSource = dataSource;
lookupEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "Name";
lookupEdit1.Properties.ValueMember = "ID";

lookupEdit1.EditValue = 101; // Select Person with ID==101
//...
lookupEdit1.EditValue = lookupEdit1.Properties.GetDataSourceValue("ID", 1); // Select Person from second row by its ID
```

Comment: Thanks @DmitryG, but I was looking after something like `comboBox1.SelectedItem = item;`, without concerning about the key of the object.

Comment: @guillegr123 The LookUp is not a ComboBox, thus you should use the key value for locating and selecting the row whose RepositoryItemLookUpEditBase.ValueMember field contains this key value... Use the following: `lookupEdit1.EditValue = item.ID;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution for select first value index:  `LookUpEdit1.EditValue=TryCast(LookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource,DataTable).Row(0).Item(0).ToString`